# How to use INSERT... ON DUPLICATE?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

**Structure table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rows_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `seet` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

[**STRUCTURE TABLE WITH TEST ROWS ON SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2423a)

**query insert:**

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `rows_id`, `url_id`, `keyword_id`, `date`, `seet`) 
VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 1, '2014-05-01 00:00:00', 1);
```

I would like insert this row or update row if table already have row with `date` = '2014-05-01 00:00:00' and `rows_id` = '1' and `keyword_id` = '1'.

In [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) i see query `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but how make insert or update in my case ?

Comment: An `Unique` constraint on Date+other columns will do? Sounds _Odd_ though

Comment: Also your title doesn't adequately describe your question.

Comment: if we use unique we can not insert rows with this key, but in my case table can have two or more rows with one value `rows_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (IODKU) does an update only if the values you insert conflict with an existing row based on a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY.

So you need to define a UNIQUE KEY over the three columns or else IODKU can't tell if the row conflicts with an existing one.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE KEY (date, rows_id, keyword_id);
```

You said in a comment above that you can have more than one row with the same `rows_id`. That's fine -- the unique constraint says that you can't have two rows that duplicate the same combination of three values in `date`, `rows_id`, *and* `keyword_id`. But you can have multiple rows that have the same value in any one of those columns, as long as the combination of the three is unique.

Here's a quick demo:

```
mysql> create table t (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    d int,
    r int,
    k int, 
    unique key(d,r,k)
);

mysql> insert into t values (1,1,1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into t values (1,1,1,1) on duplicate key update d = values(d)+1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | d    | r    | k    |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    2 |    1 |    1 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding from your question, this might help. This SQL Query will test if a row exists and update the row or create a new one based on whether or not that row already exists.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = 2014-05-01 00:00:00 AND rows_id = 1 AND keyword_id = 1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE table SET Params=values
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `rows_id`, `url_id`, `keyword_id`, `date`, `seet`) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 1, '2014-05-01 00:00:00', 1)
END
```

If the row exists (if the SELECT statement returns data) the UPDATE query will run. If the row does not exist (SELECT statement returns no data) then the INSERT INTO statement will run.